# EditText setText() not working

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am programming an Android Application that Downloads a file by URL. For that I need to send a link from one Activity to another with EXTRA_MESSAGE. Then an EditText should be changed with setText(), but the EditText is still empty. My code:

```
EditText torul = findViewById(R.id.url);
Intent intent = getIntent();
String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
torul.setText(message);
```

Before you answer to do it with:

```
torul.setText(message, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
```

Tried it, didn't work..

How I add my EXTRA_MESSAGE:

```
hl.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        String url = String.valueOf(((TextView) view).getText());
        start(url);
    }
});
private void start(String url) {
    Intent copy = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    copy.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, url);
    startActivity(copy);
}
```

Comment: Please add code where you are adding the EXTRA_MESSAGE to the intent.

Comment: Have you checked if Message has any value? You might have a problem with sending and getting the extra from the intent, rather than setting the text.

Comment: Checked it, tried it with a String, didn't worked either

Comment: String url = torul.getText().toString(); i think you forget this and then pass to next activity

Comment: So when you log the message variable, you get the right value? We need to establish where the problem is. Please try using Log.i("msg", message"); after you read the intent extra and check your log to see if you have the message you were expecting.

Comment: Is it working without using `TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE)` ?

Comment: @deluxe1 Yes the Log told me the Value I got

Comment: @ShaluTD Nope tried everything

Comment: And where are you using this code? In what method of the second activity are you trying to set the text?

Comment: In the onCreate Method

Comment: Try moving the code to the onResume() method.

Comment: What you are getting when you used intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);?

Comment: Please make sure you are passing non empty value.

Comment: @jiteshmohite The url chosen from a ListView

Comment: Thanks to @deluxe1 the  onResume Method works!

Comment: I mean String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);... What message is returning to you? Can you add log and let me know.

Comment: @jiteshmohite Not relevant anymore

Comment: Glad to hear it helps. I'll post it as an answer and you can mark it as accepted, so it can help if someone else has the same problem.

Comment: It should work inside onCreate(). That's what I know. I am not able to understand how it works in onResume()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that setText() is called in the onCreate() method, which is the first method called when the activity is created. Setting the text should be done in the onResume() method. This fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
```

use this method in second activity:

```
String message = getIntent().getExtras().getString(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
```

Comment: is this problem?EditText torul = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.url);

Answer (score 0):

I think here is problem:

```
Intent copy = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
```

You have to give context of second activity so it should be:

```
Intent copy = new Intent(MainActivity.this, YourSecondActivity.class);
```